# Multidimensional Array convert

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this multidimensional array :

```
 $a = array(
       array('id' => 1,'parent_id' => 'null'),
       array('id' => 3,'parent_id' => 'null'),
       array('id' => 4,'parent_id' => 3 ),
       array('id' => 5,'parent_id' => 4 ),
       array('id' => 8,'parent_id' => 1 ),
       array('id' => 6,'parent_id' => 5 ),
       array('id' => 7,'parent_id' => 4 ),
       array('id' => 2,'parent_id' => 1 ) )
```

I want the results below , base on the relationships `id` and `parent_id`:

```
$b = array(
        array('id' => 1,'parent_id' =>' null','children'=>array(
                array('id' => 2,'parent_id' => 1 ),
                array('id' => 8,'parent_id' => 1 )
             )
         ),
        array('id' => 3,'parent_id' => 'null' ,'children'=>array(
           array('id' => 4,'parent_id' => 3,'children'=>array(
                array('id' => 5,'parent_id' => 4 ,'children'=>array(
                       array('id' => 6,'parent_id' => 5 )
                )),
                array('id' => 7,'parent_id' => 4 )
           )),
        ))
     );
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code, hope it can help you.
`$result` is the result array which you want.

```
$result = array();
foreach( $a as $aRow ) {
    if ( $aRow["parent_id"] != 'null') {
        $aRowID = findParentRow( $a , $aRow["parent_id"] );
        if ( $aRowID > -1 ) {
            $result = insertChild( $result , $aRowID , $aRow );
        }
    }
}
```

This is a function to help you find out which key is the parent array in and return the key to you

```
function findParentRow( $arr , $id ) {
    $rowID = -1;
    foreach ( $arr as $row ) {
        if ( $row["id"] == $id ) {
            $rowID = key( $arr );
            return $rowID;
        }
    }
    return $rowID;
}
```

Insert the child array according the row number

```
function insertChild( $arr , $rowID , $child ) {
    if ( !isset( $arr[$rowID]["children"] ) ) {
        $arr[$rowID]["children"] = array();
    }
    array_push( $arr[$rowID]["children"] , $child );
    return $arr;
}
```

Copy the code with two function will work as a charm.

Remind you that there may be danger in colliding key in the array. If you have two duplicated key, this code may not work properly.